# handling username and pass in session in nodejs-express

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, session-cookies

I have a nodejs-express app running and am a newbie at this.

In my home page ('/') I have following:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    // check if the user's credentials are saved in a cookie //
        if (req.cookies.user == undefined || req.cookies.pass == undefined){
            res.render('login', { title: 'KrishiMoney' });
        }   else{
    // attempt automatic login //
            AM.autoLogin(req.cookies.user, req.cookies.pass, function(o){
                if (o != null){
                    req.session.user = o;
                    res.redirect('/home');
                }   else{
                    res.render('login', { title: 'KrishiMoney' });
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

now when I print req.cookies.user it gives me the username.Anyhow, somwhere down the routes I have an admin route:

```
app.get('/admin', function(req, res){
        var admin_username = 'admin'
        var admin_password = 'nansat'
        console.log(req.cookies.user);
        //if (req.session.user != admin_username && req.session.pass != admin_password) res.redirect('404');
        (res.render('admin_login', {title : 'Admin Page'}));
        });
```

Here when I type the same command req.cookies.user, it gives me undefined. How do I mantain the user and pass through out the routes?

Comment: Where (and) did you include the cookie middleware? Somebody will probably help you out, but it's really a bad practice to hold user/pass in the cookies.
Also, how do you know your req.cookies.user was printed correctly the first time? Where did you put the console.log?

Comment: cookie middleware is in app.js and I printed req.cookies.user in ('/') and it printed fine. I understand I should chnage the approach from cookies to sessions but for this particular case, need to know what the solution is.

Comment: What I meant is if the admin route is before the cookie middleware, you won't have access to it.

Comment: no its after the cookie middleware...

Comment: Found the issue, wasnt referencing the json object properly. Thanks.